# How to run a shell script containing an awk command

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

How to run this script (called `count.sh`)?

```
awk 'BEGIN{ x=0 ; while (x < 5) { x+=1 ; print x ; } }'
```

I'm trying to run it with `sh count.sh` but it's giving me an error.

Comment: what error? Putting that alone in a text file and running `sh count.sh` works for me, though I'd prefer in general to use a shebang line, and possibly even an awk-only script... I still don't see why yours should generate an error, however.

Comment: In general, if something is giving you an error, it's _really helpful_ if you copy the exact error into your question.

Comment: Does it complain that `awk` was not found? :)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've done for my own scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{ x=0 ; while (x < 5) { x+=1 ; print x ; } }
```

The only drawback to this approach is that the path to Awk is hard-coded. This will break when the script is exported via NFS, and the NFS client has Awk installed in a different directory (say, `/bin/awk` versus `/usr/bin/awk`.)

Setting the executable permission will allow you to directly call the script, without having to use the shell to launch it (you can also leave off the .sh extension, since by convention scripts don't include them):

```
$ chmod +x count
$ ./count
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Regarding your `#!` line, you could use `#!/usr/bin/env awk`.  I've seen it used for Python frequently.  [Wikipedia on #! portability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Portability)

Answer (score 1):

I ran you script, but I didn't get any error (although I expected to :) )

```
$ cat test.awk
awk 'BEGIN{ x=0 ; while (x < 5) { x+=1 ; print x ; } }'
$ bash test.awk
1
2
3
4
5
```

What error did you get? I expected awk will ask for an input file to process; learned a new thingie :)